# How can I install microsoftEntityFrameWorkCore Package in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hi when I want to install microsoftEntityframeworkcore in visual studio 2019 (nuget package manager) i see this error:

> severity code description project file line suppression state error
>   the feed 'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists
>   package 'microsoft.entityframeworkcore.3.1.0' but multiple attempts to
>   download the nupkg have failed. the feed is either invalid or required
>   packages were removed while the current operation was in progress.
>   verify the package exists on the feed and try again. unable to find
>   package 'microsoft.entityframeworkcore.3.1.0'.

what is the problem and your soloution?

thank you